# Electron interaction with vacuum fluctuations

Tags: quantum-field-theory, momentum, vacuum

The cause of Lamb shift is interaction between vacuum fluctuations and electron in the atom.
Will electron (or photon) in free space interact with vacuum fluctuations? How momentum will transfer vacuum fluctuations to the electron?

Answer (score 1):

Here are the higher order diagrams contributing to the [Lamb shift](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/Lamb+shift)

[image]

> (Here the dot on the right is the external vertex for the background electromagnetic field.)

The electron on the left is a "real" particle, i.e. it has an energy momentum vector , [a four vector of special relativity.](http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/Relativ/vec4.html) The photon leaving the central vertex is [virtual,](http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/Particles/expar.html) a mathematical construct under an integral for the final calculations, that has the quantum numbers of the photon but not the mass.

From the law of momentum conservation, ( which has not been falsified and is always validated in experiments) the dot on the right has to be a vertex with  another particle (or  field that can eventually transfer momentum to another real particle).

So the  electron on the left in absolutely free space, running up the y axis, will not radiate unless there is an interaction with a field or particle. Vacuum fluctuations (f type diagram) are no exception, momentum has to be conserved and a virtual loop by itself cannot conserve momentum , because by construction it has to be under an integral describing an interaction which has inputs and outputs on  real four vectors

Comment: Yet, will electron (photon) momentum in free space fluctuate, being conserved in average?

Comment: It cannot happen by momentum conservation, even for small delta(t). Violations of momentum conservation have never been observed.

Comment: At small delta(t) energy conservation violate (e.g. W boson), so momentum conservation also can be violated

Comment: no energy conservation is not violated either, in the feynman diagram calculations, and that is all we have.